# Is there a way to disable Huckabuy PageSpeed product or perhaps Cloudflare workers in general via query string or HTTP header?

Tags: cloudflare-workers

When working with the PageSpeed product from Huckabuy which uses Cloudflare workers to implement some page speed boosters I want to be able to bypass the behavior of the boosters without having to reconfigure the settings. Are there any ways to accomplish this that are exposed by Huckabuy or perhaps a generic way using a URL query string parameter or an HTTP header to bypass any given workers in Cloudflare?

---

Below is an example of what I'd like to be able to do.

`https://www.example.com?huckabuy_pagespeed=false`

If that's not possible then perhaps something specific to Cloudflare like the example below.

`https://www.example.com?disable_cf_workers=true`

Or potentially the following example HTTP header.

`DISABLE_CF_WORKER: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Huckabuy specifically, but there is no general way to bypass Cloudflare Workers with special request properties. Workers are often used to implement security policies, so it's important that they cannot be bypassed.

Of course, any particular Worker is free to implement its own bypass mechanism if it so chooses.